# Where does the Debian installer choose MBR vs GPT?

Tags: debian, debian-installer

I am able to install Debian 9.9. My query is: how does the Debian installer decide whether to use MBR or GPT? I don't see that option while installing Debian.

Comment: MBR and GPT refer to the way the disk will have a partition table, since the Debian installer gives you the choice when partitioning, it looks like you are asking the wrong question or, at least, a partial one.

Comment: he says he doesn't see that option.

Answer (score 9):

The type of partitioning to use is [determined by `partman-partitioning`](https://salsa.debian.org/installer-team/partman-partitioning/blob/master/lib/disk-label.sh#L3). The rules depend on the architecture; for 64-bit x86 systems, if the installer detects a Mac or an EFI (which means the installer was booted in EFI mode, not BIOS-compatibility mode), or if the disk to be partitioned is 2 TiB or more in size, it chooses GPT, otherwise it chooses MBR.

Comment: I don't understand the desire to cling to the old MBR partitioning scheme. Choose MBR by default, unless this or that or that, in which case choose GPT. Why even bother with this complex selection procedure, why not go straight for GPT? GPT is better than MBR in so many ways. What speaks for MBR other than fear of change?

Comment: @Johan I suspect the main concern is ensuring that the installation is bootable. On Macs, or with an EFI boot, GPT is guaranteed to be bootable; in other scenarios it’s not.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I still don't see why GPT wouldn't be bootable even on a non-EFI PC, and how does it magically become bootable on a disk larger than 2TB? Grub knows what to do with a GPT disk, and with GPT you can avoid potential problems like storing boot code outside of partitions. I'm talking about Grub Stage 1.5 which is stored in a "no man's land" right after the MBR.

Comment: @Johan I have a couple of non-UEFI PCs which ignore non-MBR disks when booting; so even though Grub can handle GPT, if the BIOS never loads the boot sector it’s not going to help much. I imagine there might be issues booting other OSs off a GPT disk on a BIOS system, even if Grub loads.

Comment: Most such problems can be worked around, but it’s better for most users if the installer tries to ensure the reboot won’t leave the user stuck...

Comment: I am trying to figure this out too. I want to install Debian using a DVD, on a system with Win10 and MBR (it was upgraded from Win7 and it remained on the old boot type...), but I am afraid that it might mess my Win10 boot. Is there any indication for the selected boot method in the installer UI before it is too late or I am risking having to restore my entire drive? :( I've never imagined installing Linux on bare metal would have so many risks of destroying everything around it...

Comment: @NoOne I have found it is always better to use GParted to create the partition type and layout you want with the appropriate labels, select manual partitioning in the installer and ask the it to use the partitions you want for `boot`, `,`, `home` etc

Answer (score 2):

Debian can be installed with modern GPT partitioning by using boot parameters to answer preseed questions (see [B.2.2. Using boot parameters to preseed questions](https://www.debian.org/releases/bullseye/amd64/apbs02.en.html)).

So basically after booting the installation medium you highlight the option to run the installer. (I chose the Graphical Installer option here.) You then hit the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key and it'll bring up the command that launches.

To the end of that command add

```
d-i:partman-partitioning/default_label=gpt
```

then you're good to go! Debian will use GPT instead of MBR.

[image: Debian12 GPT Install]

Comment: to see if this actually worked, you have to reboot into the new installation, apt install parted and run parted -l
Then it says: Partition Table: gpt